# Hausdorff dimension $\dim_H (S) = \inf \{d \ge 0 \mid H^d (S) < +\infty\}$

Tags: metric-spaces, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

I'm reading about Hausdorff dimesion. Could you confirm if my understanding (through the proof of the proposition) is correct?

---

Let $(E, \rho)$ be a metric space. Let $d \in [0, +\infty)$ and $\delta>0$.
$$
H_{\delta}^{d}(S) := \inf \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\operatorname{diam} U_{i}\right)^{d} \,\middle\vert\, \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} U_{i} \supseteq S, \operatorname{diam} U_{i}<\delta\right\} \quad \forall S \subseteq E.
$$

Then the $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is defined by
$$
H^d(S) := \lim_{\delta \to 0^{+}} H_{\delta}^{d}(S) = \sup \{ H_{\delta}^{d}(S) \mid \delta > 0 \} \quad \forall S \subseteq E.
$$

The Hausdorff dimension of $S \subseteq E$ is defined by
$$
\dim_H (S) := \inf \{d \in [0, +\infty) \mid H^d (S) = 0\}.
$$

In above formula, we adopt the usual convention that $\inf \emptyset = +\infty$.

---

I post my proof separately as below answer. This allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we have

> *Theorem 1:* Let $S \subseteq E$ and $d \in [0, +\infty)$. If $H^d (S)<+\infty$, then ${H}^{t} (S)=0$ for all $t>d$.

*Proof:* For each $\delta>0$, there exists a cover $(U_i)$ of $S$ such that $\operatorname{diam} U_{i} < \delta$ for all $i$ and
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( \operatorname{diam} U_{i} \right)^{d} <H^d_\delta + 1.
$$

We have
\begin{align}
H^t_\delta &\le \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( \operatorname{diam} U_{i} \right)^{t} \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( \operatorname{diam} U_{i} \right)^{d} \left( \operatorname{diam} U_{i} \right)^{t-d}\\
 &\le \delta^{t-d} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left( \operatorname{diam} U_{i} \right)^{d} \quad \text{because} \,\, t-d > 0 \\
 &< \delta^{t-d}( H^d_\delta + 1).
\end{align}

The proof is complete by taking the limit $\delta \to 0^{+}$. By contrapositive, we also have

> *Theorem 2:* Let $S \subseteq E$ and $d \in [0, +\infty)$. If $H^d (S) > 0$, then ${H}^{t} (S) = +\infty$ for all $t<d$.

It follows from *Theorems 1 and 2* that the cardinality of the set $\{H^d (S) \mid d \in [0, +\infty)\}$ is at most $3$. Finally, we have

> *Proposition:* $\dim_H (S) = \inf \{d \in [0, +\infty) \mid H^d (S) < +\infty\}$.

*Proof:* Let $d' := \inf \{d \in [0, +\infty) \mid H^d (S) < +\infty\}$. Clearly, $d' \le \dim_H (S)$. Assume the contrary that $d' < \dim_H (S)$. By definition of $d'$, there is $d' \le d_1 < \dim_H (S)$ such that $H^{d_1} (S) < +\infty$. Then by *Theorem 1*, we get $H^{d_2} (S) = 0$ for any $d_1 <d_2$, which contradicts the minimality of $\dim_H (S)$.